# Lower bound on a polynomial far from its zeros

Tags: inequality, polynomials, roots, approximation

Let $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{d}c_{i}x^{i} \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and assume that all its zeros are real and in $[-1,1]$.
I am interested in lower bounding the value of $|p(a)|$ in case $a \in [-1,1]$ is far from every root. That is, for every $b$ such that $p(b)=0$, $|a-b| \ge \epsilon$. Also, let $m,M$ be such that for every $i$, $m \le |c_i| \le M$.

My intuition is that the bound may be related to the largest value of a polynomial approximating a constant function on some interval, but I am not sure. Can you find some nonzero $A$ (that may depend of course on $\epsilon,m,M,d$) such that $|p(a)| \geq A$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: When you say that $a$ is far from every root, do you still want $a \in [-1,1]$ or are you interested in $a \in \mathbb C \setminus [-1,1]$?

Comment: I still want $a \in [-1,1]$, I added it. Thanks.

Comment: If $(x_j)$ are the roots of the polynomial then $$|p(a)| = |c_d| \prod_{j=1}^{d} |a-x_j| \geq |c_d| \epsilon^d,$$ but perhaps you're looking for a finer estimate?

Comment: I thought I would be able to find something finer, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do much better than what Antonio Vargas wrote. In the worst case, $a$ will be at a distance $\epsilon$ from a root of order $d$. For example, let $p(x) = c_d x^d$ and take $x = \epsilon$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. @AntonioVargas, can you make it into an answer so I can accept? Thanks.